# How to reuse Spring or Java's locale lookup code?

Tags: spring, internationalization, locale

I am doing a Spring web application.

I need to support a few locales such as ko (Korean), ru (Russian), en (English), etc.

I am able to catch what locale is from a browser via ways such as    RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request) or LocaleChangeInterceptor.

However, the browser's locale may not be what my web app supports. I have to resolve it to the closet or default locale.

Basically, I need to know how to get the resolved locale given the browser's locale AND a few locale values such as ko, ru, and en.

My understanding is that Spring has such locale resolution code because it is able to find right resource bundles given a browser's locale. I am hoping to reuse Spring's code for locale resolution, but not sure how to do it. Please note that this question has nothing to do with finding the brwoser's locale or displaying proper messages.

**EDIT**

Based on my tracing Spring's code, it appears that Spring depends on JDK to find the exact or closest locale. I just found out this and think this is what I am looking for:

Resource Bundle Lookup Order
https://sites.google.com/site/openjdklocale/design-notes/resource-bundle-lookup-order

Please note that I don't need to find right resource bundle. I just need to get the locale the existing JDK code returns given a locale in question and a few known locales. So I am hoping to reuse existing JDK's lookup code. Any idea?

I am using JDK 7.

---

Thanks for any help and input!

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Complete Reuse**

To reuse the JDK logic, you could create a property file within the classpath for each of the known locales (such as test_fr_CA.properties, test_fr.properties, test_en_US.properties, test_en.properties, test.properties).  Don't forget the root locale (test.properties) if you want to be able to match to it.  Then simply create a resource bundle for the locale in question and inspect it to see the actual locale used.

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("test", Locale.FRENCH);
System.out.println("Locale used is:"+rb.getLocale().toString());
```

The files can be created dynamically and cleaned up after the test.

**High Level Code Replication, Low Level Reuse**

You could replicate the high level code in [java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(...)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/ResourceBundle.java#ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.util.Locale%2Cjava.lang.ClassLoader%2Cjava.util.ResourceBundle.Control%29).  This is basically going through looking for a match (using your own matching logic like equal toString() representations) in a candidate list of locales reusing [java.util.ResourceBundle.Control.getCandidateLocales(...)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/ResourceBundle.java#ResourceBundle.Control.getCandidateLocales%28java.lang.String,java.util.Locale%29) on the locale in question.  If there is no match you get the next fallback locale for the locale in question by reusing [java.util.ResourceBundle.Control.getFallbackLocale(...)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/ResourceBundle.java#ResourceBundle.Control.getFallbackLocale%28java.lang.String,java.util.Locale%29) For each fallback locale you try to match a locale in it's candidate list repeating the fallback in a loop until there are no fallback locales left.  Note that the root locale will be the last candidate in each candidate list but it should be skipped unless you have exhausted all fallback locales.

This method does not require creating files.  You use a non-existent baseName in the getCandidateLocales(...) and get FallbackLocale(...) calls and compare each candidate locale to your list of known locales looking for a match.

A simple example of this would be like the following:

```
    ResourceBundle.Control rbControl = ResourceBundle.Control.getControl(ResourceBundle.Control.FORMAT_PROPERTIES);
    Locale localeInQuestion = Locale.CHINA;
    List<Locale> knownLocales = Arrays.asList(new Locale[] {Locale.CANADA_FRENCH, Locale.FRENCH, Locale.US, Locale.UK, Locale.ENGLISH, Locale.ROOT});
    String nonExistentBaseName = "bogus";

    Locale matchingLocale = null;
    Boolean reachedRootLocaleMatch = false;

    outerloop:
    for (Locale targetLocale = localeInQuestion;
            targetLocale != null;
            targetLocale = rbControl.getFallbackLocale(nonExistentBaseName, targetLocale)) {
        List<Locale> candidateLocales = rbControl.getCandidateLocales(nonExistentBaseName, targetLocale);
        for (Iterator iterator = candidateLocales.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Locale currentCandidateLocale = (Locale) iterator.next();
            if (knownLocales.contains(currentCandidateLocale)) {
                if (currentCandidateLocale.equals(Locale.ROOT)) {
                    reachedRootLocaleMatch = true;
                }
                else {
                    matchingLocale = currentCandidateLocale;
                    break outerloop;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (matchingLocale == null && reachedRootLocaleMatch) {
        matchingLocale = Locale.ROOT;
    }

    if (matchingLocale != null) {
        System.out.println("The matching locale is: "+matchingLocale.toString());
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("There was no matching locale");
    }
```

Comment: mikeatv, thanks so much for the two solutions. The fake files approach is simple and interesting, but this thing should not be ugly in Java. I like the second approach. However, I did tests and notice something. If I use Locale.CHINA as the locale in question and the known locales has Locale.TAIWAN, the result from your code is en_US from my machine. How come? Locale.TAIWAN should be the one returned, correct? What is the purpose of Locale.ROOT in your code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @curious1, Locale.CHINA will not resolve to Locale.TAIWAN but it will resolve to Locale.CHINESE.  The locales become more general as you go down the candidate list.  You drop qualifiers for script, region, and variant until you get the least general match.  You don't find "siblings" you find "ancestors".

Comment: @curious1  I don't have much to say about Locale.ROOT.  You might want to look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#ROOT) and know that it is like a default (but not JVM default locale which is the fallback) that corresponds to the resource file with only the basename (like test.properties).  If the locale in question is Locale.CHINESE and the JVM default is Locale.US but there is no file test_zh.properties, nor test_en_US.properties, nor test_en.properties, then test.properties will be used if it exists.

Comment: @curious1 If you want to deviate from the standard resolution of Locales so that Locale.CHINA would match it's "sibling" of Locale.TAIWAN you could change the matching logic.  In my example you could change `if (knownLocales.contains(currentCandidateLocale)) {...` to compare currentCandidateLocale against every member of knownLocales matching the one with longest, non-zero, common initial sub-string.  You could also use the accessors like getLanguage(), getScript(), etc. to find the sibling matches (or even descendant matches).  Again, this isn't the standard behavior and I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 5):

### Short answer

Have you checked the [official documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) (chapter *17.8 Using locales*)? You need to configure `LocaleResolver` and possibly a `LocaleChangeInterceptor` (or write your own).

### Longer description about how Spring works

**Note, that resolving client's locale is different task from getting a correct resource bundle.**

- Spring uses `LocaleResolver` to **get or set** the current locale. There are several implementations for different strategies to `LocaleResolver`:

  - `FixedLocaleResolver` - will always resolve locale to predefined value (not capable of setting different locale)
  - `SessionLocaleResolver` - stores and resolves locale to value store on session under special key
  - `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver` - this is the resolver which actually tries to get locale from the browser (not capable of setting different locale)
  - `CookieLocaleResolver` - stores and resolves locale to value stored in a browser cooke

`LocaleResolver` is used to populate `LocaleContextHolder` (btw. that is the class you should be getting locale from).

There is a second mechanism `LocaleChangeInterceptor`, which is able to set locale via your selected `LocaleResolver` based on user request parameter.

Now this infrastructure is unrelated to your resource bundles (messages.properties, messages_en.properties, ...) and the mechanism used to resolve your messages. The following examples will show why.

### Example scenarios

- Lets assume your resource bundles are:

  - `messages.properties` - with `ru` messages (default messages)
  - `messages_ko.properties` - with `ko` messages
- Lets assume you have configured `SessionLocaleResolver` with default locale `ru`
- And lets assume you have configured `LocaleChangeInterceptor`

**SCENARIO I** - First requets:

1. User makes first request to the application
2. As soon as the request reaches Spring's `DispatcherServlet` it queries `LocaleResolver` to get locale for the request
3. No locale is set on the session, so the locale is resolved to `ru` (default)
4. ...*handler stuff*...
5. Now you are rendering the webpage and you want to use `<spring:message>` tag...
6. The tag tries to resolve translation code using preconfigured `MessageSource` (`ResourceBundleMessageSource`) with **request locale** (this is the one resolved by your resolver).
7. Message source tries to load translation code from `messages_ru.properties` which does not exist, so it moves to more general file `messages.properties` (which "by accident" contains your default language - `ru`)
8. User get his page in russian language

**SCENARIO II** - User clicks link to change his language to `ko`:

1. Second request is made with query parameter `locale=ko`
2. `DispatcherServlet` resolves request locale to `ru` (this is what your locale resolver returns)
3. Before the request is handed over to your handler it goes through the `LocaleChangeInterceptor` handler interceptor.
4. `LocaleChangeInterceptor` detects `locale` query parameter and calls `setLocale` method on your `LocaleResolver`, which leads to changing request locale and storing new locale on the session for future requests.
5. ...*handler stuff*...
6. ...*view stuff*...
7. Now `<spring:message>` is calling `MessageSource` with `ko` locale.
8. Message source tries to load `messages_ko.properties` and succeeds.
9. User get his page in korean language

**SCENARIO III** - User tries to change to *invalid* locale:

1. User makes request with query parameter `locale=en`.
2. ...*dispatcher stuff*... (locale is resolved to `ko` from the session)
3. Handler interceptor changes the locale to `en` (this will be stored on the session as well)
4. ...*handler stuff*...
5. ...*view stuff*...
6. Now `<spring:message>` is calling `MessageSource` with `en` locale.
7. Message source tries to load `messages_en.properties` which does not exist so it moves to a more general file `messages.properties` and messages are translated to `ru`, even thou the request locale is set to `en`.
8. User get his page in rusian language

### Summary

Now the last example is probably what bothers you - there is no check whether the locale user selects is supported or not. If you don't want to allow user to switch to unsupported locale, then you need to either subclass some `LocaleResolver` or write your own `LocaleChangeInterceptor`.

Comment: @curious1: Spring has various strategies for resolving the locale, implemented as implementations of LocaleResolver. If none of these strategies suits you, write your own LocaleResolver implementation. +1 for this answer.

Comment: JB Nizet, thanks for yoiur input. My understanding is that the LocaleResolver you mentioned is for getting what the locale is from the browser. If yes, then that is not my goal. I hope to be able to find the exact or closest locale given a locale in question and a set of known locales.

Comment: So, implement a LocaleResolver which gets the locale from wherever you want, and then returns it if it's supported, or returns the closest supported locale if it isn't.

Comment: "implement a LocaleResolver which gets the locale from wherever you want" is what I am trying to avoid. I hope to reuse existing code from Spring or JDK. Please see my updates to the post.

Comment: There is nothing in Spring or the JDK that will return the `ru` locale rather than the `ko` locale when the actual locale is `fr` because you consider `fr` to be closer to `ru` than `ko`. The only thing that the JDK does is to load resources from the `fr` resource bundle if the locale if `fr_FR` and there is no bundle for `fr_FR`. I think what is missing, even in your own mind, is the definition of "closer locale". Neither Spring nor the JDK supports this notion of closer locale.

Comment: "The only thing that the JDK does is to load resources from the fr resource bundle if the locale if fr_FR and there is no bundle for fr_FR." -- this is exactly what I need. I just need to get the final (exact or closest) locale the existing Spring or JDK code returns or empty if there is none.

Comment: I still don't understand. The locale isn't changed or returned. When you ask for keys in a resource bundle foo, the JDK uses the locale (fr_FR for example), and looks for keys in the file foo_fr_FR.properties then foo_fr.properties, then foo.properties. But the locale is and stays fr_FR.

Comment: JB Nizet, thanks so much for your patience with me and sorry for being unclear. The process of foo_fr_FR->foo_fr->foo includes locale resolution. However, the resolution process is not simple. Please look at the link in my post. I hoping to reuse existing JDK locale resolution code to solve my need (in my case, the end result is not the resource bundle, but just a known locale value). Yes, the browser locale stays the same (fr_FR).

Comment: Maybe the confusion is from my inappropriate use of "resolution". It should be reusing Spring or JDK's locale "lookup order" code.

Comment: I've updated my answer with very detailed description how Spring's locale resolution works.

Comment: Hi Pavel, thanks for the detailed explanation of how locale resolution  works in Spring. This is the best explanation I have seen so far. However, I am looking for something else. My original post was not clear enough. I have updated. I am looking for the ways to reuse Spring or JDK's code for locale lookup order. Thanks, again!

Comment: There is nothing called *locale lookup order*. You have *resource bundle lookup order*, which is the described way how resource bundles are resolved.
So these are the two **unrelated** things: *"locale resolution based on request"*  (the `LocaleResolver` stuff) versus *"resource bundle resolution based on locale"* (the `MessageSource` stuff).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the distinction. I believe "resource bundle resolution based on locale" is what I am looking for, but I am not looking for resource bundle to use. Basically, I am hoping to have a method which (scenario 3) takes as arguments ("en", {"ru(the default)", "ko" }) and returns "ru". I wish to reuse existing code in Spring or JDK. Thanks so much for such detailed explanation.

Comment: Then you are on your own... you need to implement this yourself. You are referring to it as it is some complex problem. If I understand your needs, then it is really just checking whether a given value is in a list of supported values and if not then falling back to some default value.

Comment: Pavel Horal, thanks so much for the communication and your patience.  Your post amounts to be a good tutorial. I cannot say enough thankyou. Can I buy you a cup of coffe?